# How do I inject Git Credentials Provider rather than pick properties from bootstrap.yml or application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

In an attempt to not expose my keystore creds (in plaintext) I have a bean definition

```
@Bean
    public KeyProperties keyProperties() throws MalformedURLException {
        //snipped
        return keyProperties;
    }
```

which works as far as my keystore creds are concerned. The encrypt endpoint works and if i have cipher props in my property files in git it decrypts it properly.

Unfortunately when I set properties for git spring.cloud.config.server.git.password={cipher}snipped it throws an exception

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No decryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.TextEncryptorConfigBootstrapper$FailsafeTextEncryptor.decrypt(TextEncryptorConfigBootstrapper.java:162)
which I'm guessing is because of the keystore bean not being initialized at that point in time

Does anyone know how I can  configure a bean for the git endpoint ?

```
@Bean
    public CredentialsProvider getCredentialsProvider() {
        GitCredentialsProviderFactory gcp = new GitCredentialsProviderFactory();
        CredentialsProvider cp = gcp.createFor("url","username","password",null,false);
        return cp;
    }
```

does not seem to work.

Thanks